# Expand/collapsilbe left hand side menu using bootstrap js

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]I am new to bootstrap js. I have a requirement where in left side of the page, i should be displaying menus with one expand button on top of it. On click of that button, i must display those menu with sub-menus in it and a collapsible button on top of it. when we expand the menu, content present in the page should be adjusted. I am not sure how to start this. Attached is the image of the html page i have created. Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yuo can visit this website for reference to create off canvas navigation menu
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/
or
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/components/

Answer (score 0):

Bigslide sounds like it would be what you are looking for here

http://ascott1.github.io/bigSlide.js/